# 2D tilemap collision method

Tags: javascript, game, collision

Is this the optimal method to check for collisions in a 2d-based game?  I put together a working demo of 2D collisions [here](http://jsbin.com/qipezajiwevo/1/) (<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to move, orange blocks collide).

I currently use the following code to check for collisions:

```
function checkmove(x, y) {
  if(level[Math.floor(x/20)][Math.floor(y/20)] == 1 || level[Math.ceil(x/20)][Math.floor(y/20)] == 1 || level[Math.floor(x/20)][Math.ceil(y/20)] == 1 || level[Math.ceil(x/20)][Math.ceil(y/20)] == 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Update function:

```
function update(key) {
  switch(key) {
    case "W":
      if(checkmove(pos.x, pos.y-2)) {
        pos.y -= 2;
        break;
      } else {
        break;
      } 
    case "S":
      if(checkmove(pos.x, pos.y+2)) {
      pos.y += 2;
        break;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    case "A":
      if(checkmove(pos.x-2, pos.y)) {
      pos.x -= 2;
      break;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    case "D":
      if(checkmove(pos.x+2, pos.y)) {
      pos.x += 2;
       break;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

This is called before movement is applied the the 'player'.  The game is laid out as a 2D array of 1's and 0's for testing purposes.

Can I use fewer mathematical operations (less expensive for each tick) to check for a collision between the player and a '1' on my game grid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those refactoring will help :

idea is to test only upper-left point and bottom-right point, which should be ok 99.99999% of the time.
(Rq : i know we could test wether the second test is in fact about the same tile, but i guess that would be slower).

```
function checkmove(x, y, w, h) {
  var tileX, tileY, thisTile;
  tileX = Math.floor(x/20) ;
  tileY = Math.floor(y/20) ;
  thisTile = level[tileX][tileY]; 
  if(thisTile == 1 ) return false;
  tileX = Math.floor((x+w)/20) ;
  tileY = Math.floor((y+h)/20) ; 
  thisTile = level[tileX][tileY];
  if(thisTile == 1 ) return false;
  return true;
}
```

For your move section, there's a big issue : it is not time based. So it will run at different speed on different devices. Not good.

Define a basic game loop where you measure time. If you're interested, you can watch this fiddle i made : http://jsfiddle.net/KVDsc/

And have your game objects move by delta x = delta time * speed.

```
function update(key, dt) {
  var dx, dy, newX, newY;
  dx   = this.speedX * dt;
  dy   = this.speedY * dt;
  newX = pos.x;
  newY = pos.y;
  var kpc = 0 ;                          // key pressed count;
  if      (key == "W" && ++kpc) newY-=dy; 
  else if (key == "S" && ++kpc) newY+=dt; 
  if      (key == "A" && ++kpc) newX-=dx; 
  else if (key == "D" && ++kpc) newX+=dx; 
  if( kpc && checkmove(newX, newY) ) {
     pos.x = newX; 
     pos.y = newY; 
  }
}
```

All this should be faster. Notice that you might want to use if instead of select to enable going, say, both to the right and downward.

Comment: Thanks for the insight regarding testing the upper left and bottom right! I am using the delta time in my actual game. The demo was just a quick one that I mocked up for you guys :)

Comment: @OliverBarnwell You'll get better code reviews by not mocking up code for your question.

Comment: I'd have thought it would've been helpful to help describe the situation? I do admit that I should've made sure my code was more to the point. For that I apologise.

Comment: @OliverBarnwell If you read the faq: [On-Topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) It says to keep the original code intact.

Comment: @OliverBarnwell : the update function shrunk down from 34 to 15 lines : what you think ?

Comment: (And PS : didn't i told you, on stack overflow, that here was a better place ?? ;-) )

Comment: Yes Alchemist you were right :) Well done with the update function!

Comment: Rq : i edited the update function to avoid checking when no key is pressed.

Answer (score 8):

Before making this more efficient I'd suggest making it more readable:

in your `switch` statement you have break in both the `true` and `else` parts of your `if` statement.

```
if(checkmove(pos.x, pos.y-2)) {
    pos.y -= 2;
    break;
} else {
    break;
}
```

It would be much easier to read if you just move the break out of the if statement.

```
if(checkmove(pos.x, pos.y-2)) {
    pos.y -= 2;
}
break;
```

In [another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4491/3472) I had suggested a bit shaving optimisation that might help here. `Math.floor(number)` is equivalent to `number >> 0` this bit shifts the number by 0 bits and converts it to an integer.

```
Math.floor(x/20)
```

becomes

```
(x / 20) >> 0
```

similarly adding almost 1 *(`+ 1 - Number.EPSILON`)* and then flooring will give you the ceiling. `(number + 1 - Number.EPSILON) >> 0`

The `checkmove()` function calculates this multiple times on the one line. I'd rewrite it to calculate once.

```
function checkmove(x, y) {
  var floorX = (x/20) >> 0;
  var floorY = (y/20) >> 0;
  var ceilX = ((x/20) + 1 - Number.EPSILON) >> 0;
  var ceilY = ((y/20) + 1 - Number.EPSILON) >> 0;

  return level[floorX][floorY] == 1 ||
      level[ceilX][floorY] == 1 ||
      level[floorX][ceilY] == 1 ||
      level[ceilX][ceilY] == 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting to shift it by 0 :D I assume something like ~~ would work too :)

Comment: @OliverBarnwell I hadn't thought of that. Might be worth a try but I'd guess thats two operations where as bit shifting is one (I think I will test out that theory sometime).

Comment: Why not do `x /= 20; y /= 20;` at the start of the function? Also `ciel` should be `ceil`.

Comment: `x /= 20; y /= 20;` would only save you one inexpensive operation. Not that it would hurt either. 6 one way, half a dozen the other way.

Comment: The way you're calculating the ceiling won't work. For example, `Math.ceil(25 / 20)` is 2, but `((25 / 20) + 0.5) >> 0` is 1.

Comment: @mjolka whoops wrong trick, thats for rounding to the closest integer. `+ 1-Number.EPSILON` Or even in this case if integers are being used then `0.9` instead of `1- EPSILON` might also work.

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
if(level[Math.floor(x/20)][Math.floor(y/20)] == 1 || level[Math.ceil(x/20)][Math.floor(y/20)] == 1 || level[Math.floor(x/20)][Math.ceil(y/20)] == 1 || level[Math.ceil(x/20)][Math.ceil(y/20)] == 1) {
```

is really long and makes your code difficult to read.  You can refactor this to something much easier on the eyes:

```
if(level[Math.floor(x/20)][Math.floor(y/20)] == 1 || 
   level[Math.ceil(x/20)][Math.floor(y/20)] == 1 || 
   level[Math.floor(x/20)][Math.ceil(y/20)] == 1 || 
   level[Math.ceil(x/20)][Math.ceil(y/20)] == 1) {
```

I'm sure there's a way to simplify these checks, but I will leave that to someone more experienced to comment on.

```
if(checkmove(pos.x, pos.y-2)) {
    pos.y -= 2;
```

The reader is left to wonder what the significance of 2 is here.  You should define it in a variable so we explicitly know what it means.  It is important to make your code self documenting so that it is easier to understand.

```
if(checkmove(pos.x, pos.y-2)) {
    pos.y -= 2;
    break;
} else {
    break;
}
```

There has to be a cleaner way to implement input than if/else statements and breaks inside of a switch statement, but I do not know Javascript well enough to write the code for you.  You should be using an onbuttonpressed event in the browser to call the function if I am not mistaken.

Also I did take a quick look at the full game that you linked to.  I encourage you to post more of that code for review!